# Antithesis of "international"

Tags: antonyms, single-word-requests

If "international" is the generic word for anything that is global, what is its generic antithesis? As in:

> This is an international affair/This is an ***_*_** affair.

And please, don't give me national, because I know that's what I'm not looking for.

Comment: +1 for using "antithesis" - I wonder from whom you learned that word from haha :)

Comment: Hahahah! I told you I was using it in my vocabulary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from domestic, there's of course "**[local](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/local#Adjective)**". It's a pretty good antonym for "international" as the "generic word for anything that is global", as you put it.

For some examples: [International and local affairs](http://www.google.fi/search?q=international+local&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=%22international+and+local+affairs%22)

Answer (score 5):

***[domestic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domestic#Adjective)***

See the adjective sense #4 on Wiktionary. It works for affairs and flights etc.

Like any antonym it might not cover every sense of *international* and some senses may have antonyms specific to them but *domestic* seems to be used in a number of fields. Here are some snippets found via Google:

- *... a provider of first class* ***international*** *and* ***domestic*** *transportation services.*
- ***Domestic*** *and* ***International*** *Retail Prices ...*
- ***Domestic*** *and* ***International*** *Politics*
- *Integrating the* ***Domestic*** *and* ***International*** *Levels of Analysis*
- *Without such a concept a theory of politics,* ***international*** *or* ***domestic*** *, ...*
- *I am trying to setup shipping rules to handle* ***domestic*** *(US) and* ***international*** *(not US)*

Comment: My question has been edited.

Comment: +1. Another very common example: *international and domestic flights*

Comment: @Jonik: Thanks. I see you didn't notice flights in the second line of my answer though (-:

Comment: Ah, missed that one, sorry  :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want "parochial" - it imports locality and a lack of relevance outside of the locale.

"Local" might be what you want, but it's less strong.